# ubuntu server 18.04 shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualization

I have a vm running ubuntu server 18.04.1 LTS. It has been running alfresco for over 5 years. Now it started to shut down by itself. I didn't do any updates, I didn't change anything on the server, it's not even open for external access.

the vm is running on Unraid.

Someone could help me.

thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the log part on the shutdown.

```
May 29 04:01:06 srvalfresco systemd-timesyncd[660]: Synchronized to time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 29 04:17:01 srvalfresco CRON[9690]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-197-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-110) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #208-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 1 17:23:37 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-197.208-generic 4.15.18)
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-197-generic root=UUID=0638a370-ef33-11e8-8751-525400655308 ro
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
May 29 08:04:23 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls

Here's the anoter time:
May 30 01:16:12 srvalfresco systemd-timesyncd[643]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 30 01:16:12 srvalfresco systemd-networkd[895]: enp1s0: Configured
May 30 01:16:12 srvalfresco systemd-timesyncd[643]: Synchronized to time server 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 30 01:17:01 srvalfresco CRON[15202]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-197-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-110) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #208-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 1 17:23:37 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-197.208-generic 4.15.18)
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'ib_iser'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'arp_tables'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'br_netfilter'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco keyboard-setup.sh[422]: Não foi possível abrir arquivo /tmp/tmpkbd.LEzQc4
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'ip6table_filter'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'iptable_filter'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-modules-load[421]: Inserted module 'overlay'
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Activated swap /swap.img.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco systemd-udevd[487]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-197-generic root=UUID=0638a370-ef33-11e8-8751-525400655308 ro
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
May 30 08:06:31 srvalfresco kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
```

And the last time:

```
May 30 09:51:23 srvalfresco systemd-networkd[910]: enp1s0: Configured
May 30 09:51:24 srvalfresco systemd-timesyncd[651]: Synchronized to time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 30 10:17:01 srvalfresco CRON[5814]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 30 10:51:23 srvalfresco systemd-timesyncd[651]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 30 10:51:23 srvalfresco systemd-networkd[910]: enp1s0: Configured
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If the server is shutting itself down, there should be a reason recorded to the `/var/log/syslog` file. Understanding that reason will allow you to enjoy some stability again … though 18.04 is on its last legs 